# Remove the Parent tag in xml using php

Tags: php, xml

I am facing a problem in editing a xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  <urlset>

  <url>
   <loc>http://www.abc.com/</loc>
   <lastmod>2010-04-17T17:23:57+00:00</lastmod>
   <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
   <priority>0.50</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
   <loc>http://www.abc.com/</loc>
   <lastmod>2010-04-17T17:23:57+00:00</lastmod>
   <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
   <priority>0.50</priority>
  </url>

</urlset>
```

I want to add one more set of records starting with `<url>` with its other tags, (i.e) "loc,lastmod,changefreq,priority" and than save the xml file.For adding the new record i need to remove the parent closing tag that is `</urlset>` and than add the rest of the records and close the main tag.
Can anyone please help me solving my problem.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Approach #1: Well, you can use SimpleXMLElement::xpath in order to retrieve urlset node and then use SimpleXMLElement::addChild to add the nodes you want.

Link: http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Approach #2 (**easy one but not recommended**): Use str_replace on "</urlset>" this way:

```
$xmlDoc = str_replace("</urlset>", "<!-- YOURXML--></urlset>", $xmlDoc);
```

Either way it should not be hard.

Comment: Please don't change an xml-document with string operations like str_replace. It will eventually lead to unmaintanable code. Use an xml-parser or (easier) the DOM. PHP has several ways to modify xml.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dom = new DomDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$dom->loadXML($xml); // if it's a string, $dom->load($xmlFile) if is a file
// create the new node element
$node = $dom->createElement('url');
// build node
$node->appendChild($dom->createElement('loc', 'loc value'));
$node->appendChild($dom->createElement('lastmode', 'lastmod value'));
// (...)
// append the child node to the root
$dom->documentElement->appendChild($node);
// get the document as an XML string
$xmlStr = $dom->saveXML();
```

Answer (score 0):

I just suggest you to see this url for better idea

```
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-xmldomphp/
```